# Dashboard using google charts with two tables

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a Dashboard with column chart and a few category filters in my app, I have data like this :

```
['First name', 'City', 'Number of children'],
['Michael' , 'London', 2],
['Elisa', 'Paris', 3],
['Robert', 'Moskov', 3],
['John','LA', 1],
['Jessica', 'Kyiv', 3],
['Aaron', 'New York', 2],
['Margareth','Tokyo', 3 ]
```

but I have to visualize not this data, but a table with total amount of people with same number of children:

['1 child', '2 children', '3 children'],

[1, 2 , 4]

So when I apply some filter to first table than data in second table must be re-calculated automatically. Can I somehow bind this tables and controls together ? Or I have to put some handlers for each filter and re-calculate data manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that given your data:

```
['First name', 'City', 'Number of children'],
['Michael' , 'London', 2],
['Elisa', 'Paris', 3],
['Robert', 'Moskov', 3],
['John','LA', 1],
['Jessica', 'Kyiv', 3],
['Aaron', 'New York', 2],
['Margareth','Tokyo', 3 ]
```

You want to group by your 2nd column (number of children) to get this result:

```
[1, 1],
[2, 2],
[3, 4]
```

You can do this easily using the [group by](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) aggregation feature for data tables.

Here is sample code:

```
function drawJoin() {
  var dt = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['First name', 'City', 'Number of children'],
    ['Michael' , 'London', 2],
    ['Elisa', 'Paris', 3],
    ['Robert', 'Moskov', 3],
    ['John','LA', 1],
    ['Jessica', 'Kyiv', 3],
    ['Aaron', 'New York', 2],
    ['Margareth','Tokyo', 3 ]
  ]);

  // Group dt by column 2, and count number of entries for each.
  var grouped_dt = google.visualization.data.group(
      dt, [2],
      [{'column': 0, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.count, 'type': 'number'}]);


  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
  table.draw(dt, null);

  var grouped_table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('grouped_table'));
  grouped_table.draw(grouped_dt, null);
}
```

Feel free to try it out on [Google Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#group) (just copy-paste the above code in).

You can graph that as is, or you can transpose it using a javascript function to transcribe rows/columns in your datatable.

So you should filter using your controls on the original data table, and then create a grouping function, and draw the grouped table in your chart.

If you want the labels to read '1 child' instead of just the number 1, then you need to create a function using [SetFormattedValue()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_setFormattedValue) since the output of the group would be a number. You could mix this with the transpose function above since you're already doing work on the data table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, I don't know how I miss data manipulation part, because I've spent some time on that site playing with charts...

Comment: Sorry, but I have one more question, could you help me please? Because it's to big for comment and I don't want to ask it separately, I will ask it as reply for my first question, see my message below

Answer (score 0):

Assume I have the same data, group them and build column chart based on grouped data. Now I want to add some filters. I can easy add any filter for the column I use in grouping data, but when I add some filter for another column I got error "Invalid column label". For example if I add :

var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'control2',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Performance',
      'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': true
      }
    }
  });

everything will be fine, but my aim is to add filters for columns 'City' and 'First name' and changing their values should effect on my column chart with grouped data. If this possible to do?